# scroll to the error field in angular reactive forms on click of submit button

Tags: javascript, angular, scroll

how to scroll to error field in angular 9 consisting of reactive forms.

i tried

```
const firstElementWithError = document.querySelector('input.ng-invalid');
firstElementWithError.scrollIntoView({ behavior:'smooth', block:'start' });
```

but as there is a header in my page. the scrolled element hides behind the header. unable to add offset to the scroll.

i also tried window.scrollTo

```
var element = document.querySelector('input.ng-invalid');
var headerOffset = 45;
var elementPosition = element.getBoundingClientRect().top;
var offsetPosition = elementPosition - headerOffset;
window.scrollTo({
     top: offsetPosition,
     behavior: "smooth"
});
```

but here somehow the window.scrollTo is not working.

how to make it work?

Comment: Do you get an error or is nothing happening at all?

Answer (score 0):

Syntax wise, your code works, which means the issue is with the "top" value of the scrollToOptions object.

Make sure that the variable elementPosition actually has the value you want it to have.

Comment: i tried console.log(offsetPosition) it gives me some value. also, `window.scrollTo({
     top: 0, left:0
     behavior: "smooth"
});` is also not causing any change in the page.. i don't know if window.scrollTo is even working